# Getting Refreshed Highcharts Data Using Selenium & Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, highcharts

I'm trying to access the chart data (high chart format) from the below website using Python & Selenium. The default "1 year" option works perfect, but when I use Selenium to click "5Y" option in chart & get data, it still returns the "1Y" information.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

website = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/nps/nav/lic-pension-fund-scheme-g-tier-ii/SM003010'

# Open Website
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(website)
time.sleep(2)

# Click on 5 Year Option in Chart
driver.find_element_by_id("li_5y").click()
time.sleep(2)

# Get Data from Highcharts Series
output = driver.execute_script('return window.Highcharts.charts[2].series[0].options.data')
driver.close()
```

I've also tried an alternative for clicking 5 year data but the same issue persists:

```
driver.execute_script("get_stock_graph('','5Y','li_5y','fiveymfd_5')")
```

Any advice would be appreciated on how to get the refreshed driver page info.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Oxymoron88, It looks like every time you change a time period a new chart is created. Please try to use this JS code: 'return window.Highcharts.charts[window.Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].options.data'

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thank you so much! Could you please elaborate on what "charts.length-1" does?

Comment: It takes the last chart from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On that page, every time you change a time period a new chart is created, so you need to get the data from the last one in `Highcharts.charts` array:

```
output = driver.execute_script('return window.Highcharts.charts[window.Highcharts.charts.length-1].series[0].options.data')
```

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.charts